# Add an element to array only if is empty with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hoc can add an element to an array only if is empty, like:

```
if (myArray.length === 0) myArray.push('someElement");
```

Something similar to the `padEnd` to (which works only withs strings)

Comment: Hi Daniel, a couple of questions: 1) do you want to push the element only if the array IS empty, or if the array IS NOT empty? It would seem what you wrote in the code and what you said in natural language do not match. 2) You talk about `String.prototype.padEnd`, but `padEnd` does not check whether a string is empty or not, and can add multiple times to a string until the needed padding is reached. Do you need to add more than one element to fill the array end with x elements? Thank you in advance for your elucidations!

Answer (score 1):

## A possible candidate

If my understanding is correct, I think [`_.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaults) may be what you are looking for:

```
_.defaults(array, {0: defaultElement});
```

### A practical example

I made function called `initializeArray` so that you can see some pratical examples:

```js
/* test datasets */
const dataset1 = [];
const dataset2 = [1, 2, 3];

/* the function */
function initializeArray(array, defaultElement)
{
  return _.defaults(array, {0: defaultElement});
}

/* examples */

initializeArray(dataset1, "someElement"));
//dataset1 = Array [ "someElement" ]

initializeArray(dataset2, "someElement"));
//dataset2 = Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

### Codepen

You can also try it on codepen if you like:

https://codepen.io/jhack_jos/pen/YzpXyyK